Redirecting failed Entra ID authentication error page back to our application
Requirement:
When any error occurs during Entra ID authentication, a custom error page should open in new tab and preserving the original error message in the first tab.
Entra ID authentication flow:
Let's assume a website with Login button. When user is on the Login Page, the control is in our hand. When the user clicks on Login button, they are redirected to Entra ID for authentication. Now the control is on Microsoft Entra ID side. On successful authentication, the control will be redirected to the "Redirect URL (Our Website)" added in the registered application returning the control to us along with the ID token.
Question:
When an error occurs during the authentication process and Microsoft gives an error page like the one shared in the post, the control gets stuck there.
The error can be anything from CA policy or some other source.
Is there any way to get the control back to application when Microsoft error page comes?
I tried using "OnAuthenticationFailed" in .net core MVC 6.0.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    // Redirect to a custom error page on authentication failure
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
                    context.HandleResponse(); 
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
        };
    });

When exactly "OnAuthenticationFailed" triggers?
Thanks in advance!

If there is an error page in Entra ID and it doesn't redirect back to the app, there is nothing your app can do in that situation.
OnAuthenticationFailed occurs when processing the callback from Entra ID fails in some way (e.g. an error was returned or authorization code exchange fails).
This only happens if Entra ID redirects back to your app.

Thought so. Thank you for confirming that! Really appreciate the quick response.
